# display php code in html class attribute

Tags: php, concatenation

i am not able to concatinate php in HTML please check the code where i want concatinate.

```
1  $data['seats'] .= "<div class=\"col-xs-2\">
2      <div class=\"seat-body\">
3      </div>
4  </div> ";
```

I want to add if else condition on above line number 2 in class attribute.

Comment: if(condition is true){
$data['seat'] = "<div>true html</div>";
} else {
$data['seat'] = "<div>Another html</div";
}

Comment: no it is showing error can you please write and show

Comment: @Joseph_J has explained the exact thing in his answer. have a look there. If you're still confused, comment again and I'll write a detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here something more readable:

```
 $class = 'black';
 if($condition == 'something'){
  $class = 'white';
 }

 $data['seats'] .= '<div class="col-xs-2">
                     <div class="'.$class.'">
                     </div>
                    </div>';
```

or with a switch:

```
 switch($condition){
  case 'something':     $class = 'white'; break;
  case 'somethingelse': $class = 'red';   break;
  default:              $class = 'black';
 }

 $data['seats'] .= '<div class="col-xs-2">
                     <div class="'.$class.'">
                     </div>
                    </div>';
```

Comment: it is working but there is some issue. please read below code
<div class='\"seat-body\".$class."'> how to concatinate this?

Comment: Thank you @Bernhard

Comment: in your case it is class=\"seat-body '.$class.'\"

Answer (score 2):

Using java script would be ideal for changing classes.  But if you want a PHP solution this is how you would do it.

**UPDATED**

I removed the "if" in your ternary operator. I also prefer single quotes when concatenating html together.  So I switched your code to single quotes.

There were several other valid solutions on this page.  Please take the time to understand all of the other solutions.  It will help you down the road.

```
$data['seats'] .=
'<div class="col-xs-2">
  <div class="' . (in_array($seat, $bookArray)?('seat ladies'):('seat occupied ChooseSeat Harshad6')) . '" data-item="">
    <div class="' . (($id === 6) ? 'bla2' : '') . '">' .
      $seat .
      '<span class="seat-handle-left"></span>
      <span class="seat-handle-right"></span>
      <span class="seat-bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: No need to `\"` when you `'`

Comment: @kerbholz  Your completely right!  I literally copied his code in.  I edited it though.

Comment: where i have wrote if on line number 3

Answer (score 2):

I quite like sprintf with a ternary for things like this:

```
<?php
$html =
sprintf(
'<div class="foo %s">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
</div>',
$condition ? 'baz' : 'bat'
);
```

Comment: i like this idea

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you want to add an additional `class` to your `<div>` based on an `if` statement:

```
<?php

$class = "";

if ( condition ) {
  $class = " yourNewClass";
}

$data['seats'] .= "<div class=\"col-xs-2\">
  <div class=\"seat-body{$class}\">
  </div>
</div> ";
```

`$class` is set to empty first, then set to your desired class if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 $data['seats'] .= "<div class=\"col-xs-2\">
                <div class='".(in_array($seat, $bookArray)?("seat ladies"):("seat occupied ChooseSeat Harshad6"))."' data-item=\"\">
                <div class='".(if($id === 6) ? 'bla2' : '')."'> 
                    $seat
                    <span class=\"seat-handle-left\"></span> 
                    <span class=\"seat-handle-right\"></span>
                    <span class=\"seat-bottom\"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div> ";
```